# Covariance of an exclusion process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, heat-equation

In [Erhard and Hairer's recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.13479v1), they say that the covariance of exclusion process is given by the discrete Heat Kernel (page 61, paragraph following equation 4.11). I have not been able to make sense of this calculation. The brief notes I read up on interacting particle systems did not help. Can anyone refer me to a suitable reference for this?